# prepend in Jquery show first element as text

Tags: jquery

I have jQuery code that prepends some HTML elements, but the first element shows as text. Here is my code :

```js
var data = [{
 firstname: 'foo',
  lastname: 'bar'
}]

$(".mydiv").prepend(
  '< div class= "item" >' +
  '<div class="flyout-content">' +
  '<h5>' + data[0].firstname + '</h5>' +
  '<h3>' + data[0].lastname + '</h3>' +
  '<h4>test</h4>' +
  '</div>' +
  '</div>'
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mydiv"></div>
```

Comment: but can you describe what error/problem you are facing?

Comment: @Rush.2707 <div class ="item"> show as "<div class ="item">" in the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to the spaces around the `<` and `>` characters in the first line of your HTML string. Remove those spaces and it works fine:

```js
var data = [{ firstname: 'foo', lastname: 'bar' }]

$(".mydiv").prepend(
  '<div class= "item">' +
  '<div class="flyout-content">' +
  '<h5>' + data[0].firstname + '</h5>' +
  '<h3>' + data[0].lastname + '</h3>' +
  '<h4>test</h4>' +
  '</div>' +
  '</div>'
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mydiv"></div>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

the problem was < div class= "item" >
spacing in between div tag

```js
$(".mydiv").prepend(
  '<div class= "item">' +
  '<div class="flyout-content">' +
  '<h5>' + "data[0].firstname" + '</h5>' +
  '<h3>' + "data[0].lastname"+ '</h3>' +
  '<h4>test</h4>' +
  '</div>' +
  '</div>'
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='mydiv'>
</div>
```